# How to search for files by name inside of a specific folder Google Docs API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using V3 of the google docs api and trying to figure out how to search for a file by name inside a specified folder.

This is what I currently have:

```
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    q: 'name = "NAMEHERE" and parents in "FOLDERID"',
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} ${file.webViewLink}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search a file in the specific folder on Google Drive using the filename.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- In your script, `auth` can be used for using the method of files.list in Drive API.

For this, how about this answer?

I could confirm that you are using Drive API v3. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
q: 'name = "NAMEHERE" and parents in "FOLDERID"',
```

#### To:

```
q: 'name = "NAMEHERE" and "FOLDERID" in parents',
```

or

```
q: "name = 'NAMEHERE' and 'FOLDERID' in parents",
```

- Please use `in parents` like `'FOLDERID' in parents`.

  - At above modified query, the file with the filename of `NAMEHERE` in the folder of `FOLDERID` is retrieved. In this case, when there are several files with the same filename in the folder, those are retrieved.
- When above modification is reflected to your script of `listFiles`, I could confirm that the script worked. In this case, it supposes that the authorization can be done. If you want to know the script for the authorization, please check [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs).

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

Comment: Currently, no matter what I put in for the name, it returns no files found after adding your suggested changes, any ideas?

Comment: Also yea, you are correct on all that, sorry for not being more clear in my question :)

Comment: @AbsentmindedInsanity Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about whether my answer could resolve your issue? I couldn't understand about it from your replying.

Comment: It did not resolve it unfortunetly. I appreciate your help though!

I did find that I should be using "contains" instead of "="

With your changes and "contains" instead of "=" I was able to search for a folder inside a folder but not a file inside a folder

Comment: @AbsentmindedInsanity Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `=` of `name = 'NAMEHERE'` depends on your actual situation and your script. In my answer, I pointed out your mistake of `parents in "FOLDERID"`. About `I was able to search for a folder inside a folder but not a file inside a folder`, if you modified your script, please add your current script in your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. Could you please cooperate to resolve your issue?